# Locating a web element using selenium webdriver

Tags: web, selenium-webdriver, dynamic, element

I am new to Selenium Webdriver and was trying to automate a UI screen.The IDs of the elements are dynamically generated.

[image]

The description Orders that has been marked in Green needs to be located.
There are many other elements on the same screen with Orders , so please help me in locating this particular one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a data-attribute, e.g.:

```
By.cssSelector('[data-orders="orders"]'
```

Comment: But that ID changes after the page reload

Comment: You could then try to add a data-attribute, e.g. "data-orders" and then look for that - I adapted my answer